# Sub target property of fabric js Group is not being exported

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, fabricjs

Is there a way for me to include the **subTargetCheck** property of fabric.Group, upon serialization ?

Below is the link for fabric js group with serialization.

`JS Fiddle link` : https://jsfiddle.net/n1zs07rw/1/

I am using the latest version of fabric js library which is 1.7.19 .

**UPDATE** : 
What I did is to include the **subTargetCheck** upon serialization.

```
canvas.toJSON(['subTargetCheck']);
```

So when I check the de-serialization, the **subTargetCheck** property was included. But then when I try to move the fabric group on canvas, I am encountering an error.

The error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tl' of null
    at n._getImageLines (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n.containsPoint (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n.containsPoint (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n._checkTarget (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n._searchPossibleTargets (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n._searchPossibleTargets (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n.findTarget (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n.__onMouseMove (fabric.min.js:1)
    at n._onMouseMove (fabric.min.js:1)
```

Can anyone help me on this fabric Group issue ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello FabricJS developer here.
There was actually a bug that someone reported also on the issue tracker of fabricJS.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4444

The issue has been solved and you can upgrade to 1.7.20 to solve this issue

You could patch it manually, the point is that require a recursive fix in all the children and subchildren of a group.

What you need to do is call

```
object.setCoords(ignoreZoom = true, skipAbsolute = true);
```

For each object inside a group after restoring it.

Comment: Hi @AndreaBogazzi. Actually, I was also a participant on the reported issue of fabricJS tracker. Thanks as well for this info.

Btw, what's the use of object.setCoords(ignoreZoom = true, skipAbsolute = true); and when can I use it ? Thank you.

Comment: Ooops. I didn't know you were asturur hehehe.